# Hot reloading react redux-store connected containers with react-hot-reload

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-redux, react-hot-loader

My stack is:

- `react 15.2.1`
- `react-hot-reload 3.0.0-beta.2`
- `react-redux 4.4.5`

I am trying to use hot module replacement and everything works fine except from reloading components embedded in containers (http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html)

For example `SomeContainer`:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import SomeComponent from '../components/SomeComponent';

  // ...
  // setup mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps
  // ...

export default SomeContainer connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SomeComponent);
```

As soon as I make changes to `SomeComponent`, I can see in console that the update is handled by all parents of `SomeContainer`, but the component `SomeComponent` is not replaced / rerendered.

How do I manually implement Hot Reloading of child component `SomeComponent` or make it natively work without manually reloading `SomeComponent`

Comment: Probably not the case, but I wonder if you use the `.jsx` when importing, does that make a difference?

Comment: @DavidGilbertson i have tried to explicitly mention the file extension but with no effect - i general, webpack is configured to automatically resolve file extensions

Comment: Yeah it was a wild guess. I wonder what happens if you put the body of the `SomeComponent` file in the `SomeContainer` file. Does hot-reloading work then? There should be nothing special about containers when it comes to hot loading.

Comment: @DavidGilbertson I have tried that with no success   that's weird.... i was expecting at least that to work. In my project `SomeComponent` has more nested containers and components though, but seems like the problem is in the way how `redux`'s `connect` creates componentes - they are not handled right by `react-hot-reload`

Comment: Interesting. I'm using redux/connector/hot reloading no problem with `react-hot-loader`. My [repo is here](https://github.com/davidgilbertson/malla) if you wanna have a browse.

Comment: @DavidGilbertson Thank you, gonna check it out later

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118327/discussion-between-agoldis-and-david-gilbertson).